# How to get the date and insert it into php with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to know how can I make Laravel to get the current date and insert it into the database with the rest of the data from a form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can do it on the db setting a default date. `TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` will do the trick. This way the field is autopopulated as soon as you create the record without the need to handle its value

Comment: You'd presumably need to add it as an extra parameter in your query. Show us how you submit this data currently and maybe we can be more specific. Or as Lelio says you can just let the database handle it

Comment: Show the code you're using to insert. If you're inserting via a model, it will automatically update the timestamps.

Comment: include your current code here in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel comes with this functionality out of the box.

You can add this code to your migration:

```
$table->timestamps();
```

This will create a `created_at` and `updated_at` field in your database which are automatically filled.

---

Or if you want to don't want to do it within Laravel, you can do one of these:

- Set the default value of the column to: `TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`
- Assign the value in the controller: `$model->created_at = date('Y-m-d');` and save it normally.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. And sorry for such a simple question

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has the ability to save create and update timestamps in the database automatically.

All you need to do is add `$table->timestamps()` to your migration. This will create two new fields: `created_at` and `updated_at`. Laravel will automatically populate those fields when creating/updating a model.

Answer (score 0):

For automatically insertion you can use

```
$table->timestamps();
```

And for static entry you can use

```
 $table->Date('Date_Of_Birth');
```